# Change event not firing on text input using jquery in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, input, onchange

I have a problem with a jquery change event on a text input that works as expected in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome. I also have a keyup event on the text input to manipulate the input as it is entered, but when the input is done I need to run some extra code. I tried using the 'blur' event and the 'focusout' event as someone here had suggested as a substitute, but then I couldn't change focus at all -- the input kept grabbing it back somehow. Here is the code:

```
 $('.textInput').keyup(function(event) { /* do stuff */ });
 $('.textInput').change(function(event) { alert('Changed!'); /* do other stuff */ });
```

and the html:

```
 <input type="text" class="textInput" value="" />
```

I am using jQuery 1.6.3.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
H.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/R8VBY/) in Chromium 14/Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: can you post the error that Chrome gives you? If you do Inspect Element (right click on page) it should show you what the error is.

Comment: What other js code do you have loaded on the page that would make it grab focus back? Change only fires when focus changes, that that's probably why.

Comment: There is no error, the change event just doesn't fire. Since it works for others, I changed tack and narrowed it down to something in the keyup handler that prevents the change event on Chrome. It is not my code in there so I have worked around it by running the code from the change handler in the keyup handler -- not the most efficient but no major harm done. When I have some time I will try to find the offending code in the keyup handler. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 12):

The change event will not fire unless the input focus switched to other controls

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input` event that works like a charm:

```
$('#search-form .term').bind('input', function(){
  console.log('this actually works');
});
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/brandonaaskov/1596867

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.textInput').keyup(function (event) {
                var obj = $(this);
                if ((event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which) === 13) {
                    $('#result').text('Enter has been triggered.');
                }
            }); ;

            $('.textInput').change(function (event) {
                var obj = $(this);
                $('#result').text('Input text has been changed:' + obj.val());
            }); ;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="result"></span>
    <br />
    Enter some text and press enter:
    <input type="text" class="textInput" value="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's a bug on Google Chrome that causes the 'change' event to not fire if something has been changed by the 'keyup' event:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92492

The issue seems to be open since May 2, 2013.