# change event on input in angular 2 is not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I want when user typing in input execute a function,like this :

```
<input
   id="cell"
   type="text"
   name="cell"
   ngControl="cell"
   (change)="topersian($event)"
>

topersian($event){
  $event.currentTarget.value = $event.currentTarget.value.toPersianNumber();
}
```

I don't want to use `(keypress)` or `(keyup)` because user can see the English number.

I use `[(ngModelChange)]` but can't access to `$event`, just get value!
how to fix this problem ? or anybody have A better solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what the problem with `(keypress)` and `(keyup)` is?

Comment: user can see the changes...i mean have delay 1 convert to 1 persian...Do you understand?

Comment: What about `(keydown)` then?

Comment: The problem with the `change` event seems to be http://stackoverflow.com/a/21042928/217408 The chrome bug still doesn't seem to be fixed.

Comment: yes `keydown` have problem like this...aaah shit

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like [Change event not firing on text input using jquery in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407770/change-event-not-firing-on-text-input-using-jquery-in-chrome)

The `input` event should do what you want

```
<input (input)="topersian($event)>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
(ngModelChange)="topersian($event)
```