# File input not working with vanilla Xiaomi Redmi series

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

The file input only works if I change the Xiaomi native launcher for another in the Play Store, obviously I can't force the users to do that.

```
<input type="file" name="file" #fileInput (change)="fileChange($event.target.files)">
```

No errors neither logs prints anything.

Steps to reproduce:

- Click in input file
- Select a file (any .pdf for example)
- Nothing happens in the event of (change)

Comment: What happens if you just pass the $event to the `fileChange`? does it get called?

Comment: You should attach a Remote chrome devtools and see what is happening when you use the phone

Comment: @ForestG  I tried both options but no log nor any info.
fileChange never triggers in this device, only if native launcher is changed

Answer (score 0):

Use 'ion-input' tag instead of the regular 'input' tag. Use the (ionChange) instead of (change). That should help

Comment: Same issue, no log in console (debugging with Chrome) neither the ionChange is triggered. 0 debug info given.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it without any extra info:

```
<input (change)="fileChange($event)">
```

Might be a problem about [your input not being focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407770/change-event-not-firing-on-text-input-using-jquery-in-chrome) in time of the change event too.